# How to remove white space of the tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have added tab bar controller to my view controller, a white space is visible in the top of my view. I have tried to set my navigation bar visible to false in viewwillappear function, it didn't work. I have unchecked under bar in extended edges, that didn't work either. Someone please guide me through this problem.

**My Storyboard**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxOYH.png

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
    guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarController")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**HomeVC.swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Click your navigation controller, select attribute inspector at the right side of Xcode. unselect show navigation bar option in the navigation controller section as shown in image [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried that too, it didn't work.

Comment: can you share your code GitHub link? just chunk of code you are getting the issue

Comment: It is not the navigation bar that is visible in the top, it is the tab bar controller and I don't know how to make that disappear.